# How did Git and Mercurial develop so similarly at the same time?

Tags: git, mercurial, dvcs

Git and Mercurial follow similar models and have similar terminology.  Mercurial's initial release was was only 12 days after Git's.  How did these two projects, in initial development at the same time, end up so similar?  Does anyone know the history?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837/what-is-the-difference-between-mercurial-and-git

Comment: The telephone was independently invented by two people at nearly the same time, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both were necessary because of problems with bitkeeper so they were both developed at the same time to solve the same problem.

If you want a distributed version control system, that looks like bitkeeper, then from the user's point of view any implementation is going to be pretty similar. Internaly they are quite different

Comment: Well that explains it.  I did a quick check of the [BitKeeper commands](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:uKB9l0SKirEJ:www.bitkeeper.com/bk_refcard.ps&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com), and it does seem like both Git and Mercurial "borrow" terminology from there.